# uibPopover not showing after promise resolves on first click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, popover

Relevant info:
writing in angular 1.5.8. 
bootstrap-ui 1.1.2. 
uibPopover is used to display my popover.

I have an issue with trying to show a popver that relies on data from a promise

relevant angular service get call:

```
       this.getDetails = function (req) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            return $http.get("/api/getDetails?id=" + req).then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data.ResponseData);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            );
        }
```

angular controller code:

```
$scope.showPopOver(req){
      angularService.getDetails(req).then(function(response) {

            $scope.vm.myPopOverData = response;

            $scope.vm.htmlPopOver = {
                templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html',
                title: 'Details'
            };

        });
}
```

html where popover lives:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" tabindex="0" popover-placement="right-top" uib-popover-template="vm.htmlPopOver.templateUrl" popover-title="{{vm.htmlPopOver.title}}" 
                   popover-trigger="outsideClick" ng-click="showPopOver(data)" >Click me</a>
```

On the first click of my anchor tag, the data is retrieved but no popover will show. The second click, popovers will show, however the api call hasnt returned with the data that should be shown (this is a table with an ng-repeat on the ). It inevitably will be set after the promise finishes resolving but it would be nice for the popover to remain closed/hidden while waiting for a response from the server.

So, I guess I have two problems. The first click on a popover does nothing but retrieve data. The other issue being the popover appearing before data has been retrieved.

Is there an easy/elegant solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use `popover-is-open="isOpen"` attribute to pass on state of popover, when you want it show up just toggle `isOpen` flag and that's it.

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" tabindex="0" 
  popover-placement="right-top" uib-popover-template="vm.htmlPopOver.templateUrl"
  popover-title="{{vm.htmlPopOver.title}}" 
  popover-is-open="vm.isOpen"
  popover-trigger="outsideClick" ng-click="showPopOver(data)">
    Click me
</a>
```

**Code**

```
this.getDetails = function (req) {
    return $http.get("/api/getDetails?id=" + req).then(
        //removed unnecessary promise 
        function (response) {
            vm.isOpen = true;
            return response.data.ResponseData;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that there will be several rows then bound to the same boolean value which will cause all popovers to open regardless of being clicked.

I have thought about 'priming' my list of objects with their own bool values but I wanted to see if there was a better way before I cluttered up my tidy code. Thank you for the reply, though